# fatal error occures when passing the SKNodes position in swift spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game with swift and I'm getting the 
" fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
at shootMarsh method. All I want to do is to pass the nodeNameA?.node?.position to the method shootMarsh to use the position of the node. Since I'm new to swift and spritekit , some tips and examples will be really helpful!

```
  if ((nodeNameA.categoryBitMask == category_marsh && nodeNameB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bullet) ||
            (nodeNameA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bullet && nodeNameB.categoryBitMask == category_marsh)) {

                var pos  = nodeNameA?.node?.position


            shootMarsh(pos!)  //Getting the error here

                if contact.bodyA.node != playerSprite {
                    nodeNameA.node?.removeFromParent()
```

Comment: `print(pos)` first because I think it is nil at run time.

Comment: The problem is that it is not nil for a while but it turns nil in the midst of the shooting.Is there a solution to pass the value without showing up the error ?  There is no problem when I run it on my device. But whene I run it on the emulator the error shows up.

Comment: What version of Xcode you are using?

Comment: I'm currently using Xcode 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if let` to unwrap optionals this way:

```
if let pos  = nodeNameA?.node?.position{
     shootMarsh(pos)
}
```

Now it will not crash when your `pos`instance become `nil`.